# C++ Block Mouse Down from being used by operating system but allow it to be seen by my program

Tags: c++, windows, mouse, hook

How would I go about blocking the mouse down event so that the operating system won't act on it or won't receive it but I can still see that the user has their mouse down by hooking the mouse and waiting for this message?  I am writing a screen capture program so this is a fairly important part of this.

This is for windows.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am writing this for windows.

Comment: Use SetWindowsHookEx() to set a WH_MOUSE_LL hook.  Return a non-zero value from your hook callback to swallow the message.

Comment: If you set this as an answer Hans I will accept it as an answer.  Thank you very much this is exactly what I was looking for.